# Как правильно хранить репо Git для множества IDE?

Tags: git, github, ide

Один репозиторий с кодом клонируется на несколько компьютеров с VS13/15/17, Eclipse, Netbeans и пр., каждый из них создаёт свои файлы проекта.

Если бы я не хотел создавать новый проект на новом компьютере для моего гита, можно ли оставить все файлы как есть? Если можно, как их организовать?

Я по привычке вношу все файлы проекта в .gitignore, но мне придётся создать новый проект на новом компьютере для того, чтобы продолжить работу над кодом.

Comment: Вроде в .net принято хранить проект в гите. А версии должны быть достаточно совместимы, если коммитить минимальную.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно, пожалуйста, подробнее?

Comment: *"по привычке вношу все файлы проекта в .gitignore"* - избавьтесь от этой привычки.

Comment: @user7860670 есть польза от файлов проекта в репозитории?

Answer (score -1):

У вас несколько вариантов:

1. Добавить все файлы в ваш репозиторий, если вы часто разворачиваете на новом ПК, то это может быть удобно, правда размер репозитория GIT вырастет до неприятных размеров.
2. В GIT только исходники, репозиторий где-то удалённо и после разворачивания организовать доставку неким скриптом либо пакетным менеджером (composer для php, npm или bower для JS).

P.S. т.е. клонировали GIT, запустили скрипт(либо пару команд в терминале) и у вас докачались все зависимости и пакеты.